# how show action works in grails 2.3.0 controller

Tags: grails, controller, action

```
def show(Human humanInstance) {
    respond humanInstance
    //[Q1] In the above action humanInstance is works like Command object
    //(I read it in grails doc) they said here call the Domain.get(id) but
    //where the line [ Domain.get(id) ] written physically or where it executed when 
    //show call?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.3.0 the line of code which invokes the “get” method for this particular scenario is at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v2.3.0/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/api/ControllersApi.java#L427.

Is that what you are looking for?